# I can't view the information I sent with js in postman

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, post, postman

With the code below, I can enter information in my MySQL table in the post method and the information is recorded in the table. I also check it in the js terminal. With the "node api.js" command, it appears that the last information is registered. but the last added info doesn't show up when I look with the postman.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

let cevap;

const baglanti = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'example',
    user: 'example',
    password: 'example',
    database: 'example'

});

baglanti.connect();

baglanti.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;

    cevap = results;
    console.log(results);
    baglanti.end();
});

app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    res.send(cevap);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("worked"); 
});
```

if you look at the first photo, I can see the information added in the terminal, but the last entered information is not visible in the second photo, that is, on the postman screen.

1. [Terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lMTz.png)
2. [Postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TSvC.png)

What I want is to be able to view all added users in postman. When I add a new user, see it instantly from postman (already registering to MySQL table)

Comment: You are selecting users and save that to the variable. The issue is - nor new values would be available that way. Also if you ask for the users too early, the variable is still undefined therefore not returned

Comment: please help what should i do

Comment: I can only share the tutorial for frontend developers i wrote some years ago - it is not the best (directory structure, nor rouiting structure etc, as express was only 2 days, and then we moved to nestjs) but it actually shows the database usage, so might help you a bit https://github.com/itmaginationdemos/Trainings/blob/main/Day2-MySql/ with several endpoints already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You HAVE TO query fresh data from the databse EVERY time you want your fresh data.

Ofc. you could cache it or something but thats probably too advanced for this case.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const sql = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'example',
    user: 'example',
    password: 'example',
    database: 'example',
});

sql.connect();

app.post('/users', (req, res, _next) => {
    sql.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;

        console.log(results);
        res.send(results);
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```